# Manipulate switching datasources when pasted in new notebook

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, scoping

I have a notebook to build a `Manipulate`.  I perform an evaluation of the notebook and copy & paste the `Manipulate` into another notebook that I am using to write the report. I do this several times for different datasets.

What I have found is that all the `Manipulate`s switch to the dataset of the last pasted `Manipulate`. How can I prevent this from occurring. I was under the impression that `Manipulate` kept itself separate from other manipulates as it is basically `DynamicModule` underneath.

The `Manipulate` has a lot of associated code so I cannot paste it all multiple times into the report notebook. A solution that allows only to copy and paste the output cell is desired.

**Minimal example:**

```
data = Range[10];
Manipulate[data[[;; n]], {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

1. Run the above and copy & paste the output cell into a new notebook
2. Change `data = Range[10];` to `data = Range[10,100,10];`.
3. Run and copy & paste the output cell below the first pasted output cell in the new notebook.
4. Both `Manipulate`s in the new notebook now show `Range[10,100,10]` instead of only the second pasted one showing this range.

Comment: Try `data = Range[10];
With[{data = data},
 Manipulate[data[[;; n]], {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
 ]`

Comment: Or `DynamicModule[{data = data},
 Manipulate[data, {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}]
 ]` p.s. if you copy to the notebook with unique context you don't have to change anything because the definitions contain a reference to ``$CellContex`data`` not a ``Global` `` one.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That works. (+1) Please post an answer. Any idea why `Manipulate` is not correctly (as I understand) scoping its variables. We should not have to resort to `With`?

Comment: @Kuba That works. (+1) Please post an answer.  Any idea why `Manipulate` is not correctly (as I understand) scoping its variables. We should not have to resort to `DynamicModule`?

Comment: @Edmund It scopes only variables declared in *var spec* (here `n`). `SaveDefinitions` only save others, doesn't localize them additionaly.

Comment: @Kuba All my notebooks have unique context; I don't use ``Global` ``.  `CellContext` is set to `Notebook` in the *Global Preferences*. Still this is happening.

Comment: @Kuba May you include that tidbit in your answer.

Comment: With this example or with the big one you have? I checked and with global setting with Notebook context it behaves correctly in different notebooks.

Comment: @Kuba With this one, please. Dare I ask you restart Mma with the new `CellContext` setting and try the steps above. (Version 10.4.1 on Win 7 Ent with Service Pack 1)

Comment: @Edmund you mean you have multiple Manipulates in the same notebook? Then no, you need `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @Kuba Correct. I paste multiple times with each one having been run on a different dataset.

Comment: @Karsten7. That is how I understood it. So you are suggesting this is a bug?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Manipulate[data[[;; n]], {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, {data, None}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]` should localize `data` also. (Similar to the `DynamicModule` version Kuba suggested). Don't think it's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `Manipulate` doesn't apply any scoping of it's own outside of the controls you define, in your instance `n`. So you just need to scope the variable at the time you instantiate the `Manipulate`, my goto for this is `With`, but Kuba's suggestion using `DynamicModule` might be more suitable*. e.g. Scoping this way you can run the following in a single cell and get two objects that behave as you expect.

```
data = Range[10]; 
With[{data = data}, Manipulate[data[[;; n]], {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True] ]

data = Range[10,100,10]; 
With[{data = data}, Manipulate[data[[;; n]], {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, SaveDefinitions -> True] ]
```

*I'm interested to hear from anyone who knows these things well.